# Triple Integrals in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: calculus

Use spherical coordinates to to find the volume of a solid bounded above by
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = z$ and below by $z$ $=$ $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Comment: from the first equation I get p^2 = pcos(phi), and from the second one I get pcos(phi)= p|sin(phi)| , after that I'm completely lost as to find any bounds

Comment: Are you on line? @thebottle394

Comment: yes I am online

Comment: @thebottle394: did you see my approach below?

Comment: Is the RHS of the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=z$ correct?

Answer (score 3):

**Just** hints for the limits:

$$V=4\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\theta=\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{r=0}^{1/2} r^2\sin^2\theta dr d\theta d\phi$$ wherein $x^2+y^2+(z-1/2)^2=\frac{1}{4}$. See below:

[image]

Comment: The sphere is not centered at the origin.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Oh! :-0. I thought there is typo. Thanks. I'll edit it. Thanks.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Please have a look dear dr. I hope I could do that for the OP.

Comment: Beautiful graphic!

Comment: @amWhy: It is like a Crown, Amy. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, indeed! ;-)

Comment: What software do you use to draw such graphics?